# keep counting up throughout multiple for loops

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a loop within a loop like this:

```
//stuff here to determine what $my_var will be
for($i=0;$i<count($my_var);$i++) {
    //stuff here to determine what $anothervar will be
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $anothervar; $y++) {
        //help needed in here
        echo $y; //makes it so count starts over each time it goes around
    }
}
```

my_var is going to loop certain amount of times, not always the same amount.

The inner loop also is a random number.

An output could look like this:

```
1
    1,2
2
3
4
5
6
    1,2,3
```

So in first main loop the inner loop happened twice. in 6th main loop, the inner loop happened 3 times.

what i would like to do is instead of the inner loop starting over from 1 each time, i want it to keep counting up. so i want output to be like this:

```
1
    1,2
2
3
4
5
6
    3,4,5
```

Let's say the 3rd main loop has some inner loops in it, we'll make it 4 inner loops, then the output should be like this:

```
1
    1,2
2
3
    3,4,5,6
4
5
6
    7,8,9
```

How would I do a continuous count up in a loop within a loop?

EDIT

Here is what ended up working:

```
//stuff here to determine what $my_var will be
$y = 1;
for($i=0;$i<count($my_var);$i++) {
    //stuff here to determine what $anothervar will be
    for (; $y <= $anothervar; $y++) {
        //help needed in here
        echo $y; //this now continues to count up instead of starting over each main loop
    }
    $y = 1;
}
```

Comment: Someone answered and i was going to mark as correct answer, because it was close enough. all i did was add the second y=1, but that person deleted their answer.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, that edit i did is not correct either. back to the drawing board.

Comment: post full code of the loops... need to see what influences the second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$x = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($my_var);$i++) {
    //stuff here to determine what $anothervar will be
    for ($y = 1; $y <= $anothervar; $y++) {
        $x++;
        echo $x; // now x is incremented every inner loop by 1
    }
}
```

Just changed 3 lines of your first code example.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you see `$y = 1` you're setting it back to 1. So if you want it to continue increasing, don't do that – except at the beginning, outside the loop.

```
$y = 1;
for($i=0;$i<count($my_var);$i++) {
    //stuff here to determine what $anothervar will be
    for (; $y <= $anothervar; $y++) {
        //help needed in here
        echo $y; //this now continues to count up instead of starting over each main loop
    }
}
```